# retrofit call the second method when the first method is finished

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit

I have two methods the first is named `first()` and the second is named `second()`;
The `first` is a retrofit call :

```
 private void first() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiConge.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiConge api = retrofit.create(apiConge.class);

        Call<String> call = api.getCongeByUserId("Bearer " + token_data, id_data);

        //finally performing the call
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() { ...
```

And the second is also a retrofit call :

```
 private void second() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiConge.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiConge api = retrofit.create(apiConge.class);

        Call<String> call = api.getCongeByUserId("Bearer " + token_data, id_data);

        //finally performing the call
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
```

In my case i need to execute the second method when the first method call is completely finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call second method when first call is done.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<String> response) {
        second();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        
    }
});
```